# Best practice for sending single message to multiple queues in IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

as the title suggests i am after the best way of sending a message to mutliple recipents with IBM MQ 8. 
I am new to using MQ and wanted to know the way that is generally accepted as the best/yet simplest manner of distributing  messages to multiple recipeints.

My thought was just to enable 'some function' that allows all incoming mesages to be put to multiple queues to be then consumed by a different consumer on each queue.

Any help gratefully recived.

thanks in advance
Scott

Comment: As I understand your question it looks like you need a "topic" instead of "queue". Queue is for single recipent, topic for multiple.

Answer (score 0):

[Pub/Sub](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q004870_.htm) is a way to send to multiple consumers.  You may also want to consider [multicast.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q003420_.htm)